# Open Terminal Window with Predefined Environment Variables (Including `PATH`)

Tags: terminal, finder, bash, environment-variables

I'm trying to create a `.command` file which will open a terminal window with predefined Environment Variables (Including `PATH`).

I tried this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Adding CMake to Path
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Shared/CMake/CMake.app/Contents/bin/:

# Adding Ninja to Path
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Shared/Ninja/:

# Adding GCC to Path
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/gcc-8.2/bin/:

echo Path Updated
```

Yet when I double click on Finder I get this:

```
Path Updated
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...none found.

[Process completed]
```

Namely it is gone.

Is the a way to have a file which does the following (Maybe it has to be 2 different files, I don't know):

1. If clicked from finder will open a new terminal window with all the variables defined / updated (Including the `PATH`).
2. If run from terminal will update the current terminal state.

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to explicitly start an interactive `bash` shell at the end of your script in order to keep the window open when you open the `.command` file from Finder.

The following revision of your script demonstrates that and also streamlines other aspects of your code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Note: $PATH already exists as an exported variable, assigning to it
#       again preserves that status, so there's no need to call `export` below.

# Adding CMake to Path
PATH+=:/Users/Shared/CMake/CMake.app/Contents/bin/

# Adding Ninja to Path
PATH+=:/Users/Shared/Ninja/

# Adding GCC to Path
PATH+=:/usr/local/gcc-8.2/bin/

cat <<EOF
Path updated to:

  $PATH

Starting interactive Bash shell...
EOF

# Start an interactive Bash shell that inherits this script's environment
# and keeps the window open.
# Using -l makes the interactive shell a login shell, which makes it
# load the same initialization files as shells created by Terminal.app,
# notably, ~/.bash_profile
# Be sure that ~/.bash_profile doesn't override $PATH.
exec bash -l
```

This `.command` file will also from an existing *terminal* window, but note that you will enter an interactive *child* shell -  `exit`ing from that child shell will return to you to the original one.

---

It is possible to amend your script so that if you invoke it from an existing terminal window (shell), it modifies that shell's environment *directly*, but you then have to `source` / `.` the script on invocation (e.g., `. ./script.command`):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Note: $PATH already exists as an exported variable, assigning to it
#       again preserves that status, so there's no need to call `export` below.

# Adding CMake to Path
PATH+=:/Users/Shared/CMake/CMake.app/Contents/bin/

# Adding Ninja to Path
PATH+=:/Users/Shared/Ninja/

# Adding GCC to Path
PATH+=:/usr/local/gcc-8.2/bin/

# Determine if this script is being sourced.
[[ $0 != "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && sourced=1 || sourced=0

cat <<EOF
Path updated to:

  $PATH

EOF

if (( sourced )); then # sourced from the calling shell.
  # The calling shell's environment has been modified - nothing more to do.
  :
else # otherwise: launched from Finder or from a terminal without sourcing
  # A new interactive shell must be launched for the environment modifications
  # to take effect and, if launched from Finder, to keep the terminal window
  # open.
  echo "Starting new interactive Bash shell with modified environment..."
  # Using -l makes the interactive shell a login shell, which makes it
  # load the same initialization files as shells created by Terminal.app,
  # notably, ~/.bash_profile
  # Be sure that ~/.bash_profile doesn't override $PATH.
  exec bash -l
fi
```

Comment: Good work all, the conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82745/discussion-on-answer-by-mklement0-open-terminal-window-with-predefined-environme).

Comment: @bmike, The problem is I can't talk on chat (Not enough reputation) so basically you left me out. Also I'd rather have the beginning of discussion left here.

Comment: Why can’t you chat @Royi ? Youve got more than 20 rep required ...  let us know and I’ll see if I can get you invited explicitly to the conversation